# npm module rimraf doesn't work on OSX but does on Windows

Tags: node.js, macos

Rimraf doesn't work on OSX but does on Windows with the following code:

```
rimraf('dist/**/*{bundle,icons}*', err => err && console.warn(` rimraf error: ${err}`))
```

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_, we're not omniscient.

Comment: Rimraf removes files. It does not remove the files of the given glob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is root access. When I use the sudo npm run script command it works.